# Why do we declare constant lat and lon value

Tags: arduino-uno, tinygps

static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

What does this mean?

https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/blob/master/examples/FullExample/FullExample.ino

The above link contains the full example program of that line.

This line is from tinygps++ library for extracting the coordinates and displaying in a table format. I'm using arduino uno, GSM module and GPS module to extract the coordinates and transmit it as message. Can anyone explain what dies this constant value mean and why do we use this?

Comment: Unlike in movies, I hardly think London will ever move.

Comment: This constant value is there at tinygps++ full example program and I don't know about this constant value? Do you know any exact answer? Also what type of algorithm is used here for the entire program. I'm new to arduino and so I just wish to have a knowledge of it. Is there any specific algorithm being used to extract the exact gps coordinates using gps module and arduino?

Comment: These are the GPS coordinates of London. If you want to know the exact location google the coordinates. In your comment you have more questions about an example program, but you never included the program in your question, nor did you link to it. How should we answer your question? We don't know, what sketch you are talking about, so we cannot know, how this one line ties into the rest of the program

Comment: We declare those because the program in which they are declared wants to use that information in some way. Without knowing what the program is we can't say why it might want to know that information. Maybe it wants to work out how far from London you are.

Comment: https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/blob/master/examples/FullExample/FullExample.ino

Comment: This link contains the full program. Sorry to attach the link, since the program to too lengthy.

Comment: I'm currently working on a project, where the my location coordinates is to be sended as message using GSM module. The GPS coordinates are extracted using gps module. These are connected to arduino uno board. Tinygps and tinygps++ library is being used for this project. This program is an full example program which is default in tinygps++ library

Comment: Please add all this information and questions to the text of your original question, not in the comments. They are temporary and please should not need to read the full comment stream to get the needed information.

Comment: If you want us to give you a detailed explanation of every single line of code of the program you are linking to, you are in the wrong place. This site is for specific, well-targeted questions. If you do did study that program and have a **specific** question, then ask, and include the relevant bits in the question itself. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I was actually asking for a particular line, which was mentioned 1st. static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

Comment: @Kwasmich lol ... that is example code ... it is written using proper programming convention... it needs to be clear so that most people would immediately know what to do to modify the code for their needs ... using descriptive names of variables makes the code easier to read, and the code requires less comments ... if the constants were used directly then the OP would probably be asking `what is this 51.508131?`

Comment: @tharrunkumar imagine that you are writing a program that calculates the circumference and the area of a circle from an input of a radius parameter .... which would be clearer to read? ... `c = r * 2 * 3.14159` `a = r ^ 2 * 3.1459` ... or ... `pi = 3.14159` `circ = 2 * radius * pi` `area = radius ^ 2 * pi`

Answer (score 2):

Static variables are allocated storage only once in a program lifetime
The const keyword specifies that a variable's value is constant and tells the compiler to prevent the programmer from modifying it and you can't change const variable's value
and i guess you know double is a data type that can save floating point numbers
that line declare two variables with names `LONDON_LAT` and `LONDON_LON` and both of them are in one line
and because london's latitiude and longtitude doesn't change the `const` keyword is used

also i guess because those variables are constants you can use `#define` visit https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/further-syntax/define/

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to declare variables the strictest possible way. So if you don't intend to change the value of LONDON_LAT at runtime, declare it as **const**.

This allows the compiler to alert you if your code tries to modify it, and it often allows the compiler to optimize the code.